# how to solve scikitlearn model_selection train_test_split problem?

Tags: python-3.x

While doing the train test split using sklearn train_test_split, I am getting below error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0) NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-17-65776283812c> in <module>
          1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    ----> 2 X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO, can you please add your complete code. Error is showing that you have not defined input feature set X.

Answer (score 0):

Did u declare x array? Like what x is equals to. Example X= fake.values?.

example code

## load the dataset

```
df=pd.read_csv("datasets//ccfraud.csv")
print (df.shape)
```

```
#remove the field from the data set that we dont want to include
del df['Merchant_id']
del df['Transaction_date']


#replace categorical data with one-hot encoded data
features_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Is_declined','isForeignTransaction','isHighRiskCountry'])

#remove the sale price from the feature data
del features_df['isFradulent']
features_df.columns
```

## create the x and y arrays

```
x=features_df.values
y=df['isFradulent'].values
print("arrays created")
print("===========Now running T T S =======")
#split the data set in a training set (70%) and a test set (30%)
x_train, x_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x , y, test_size=0.3,random_state=7,shuffle=True)
print("====Train, Test, Split Shuffled===")
```